# Android Volley HTTP POST returns javascript

Tags: javascript, java, php, android, android-volley

I am trying to register a user using Volley. However, instead of returning an echo from my php script, it returns this weird message.

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/aes.js" ></script>
<script>function toNumbers(d){var e=[];d.replace(/(..)/g,function(d){e.push(parseInt(d,16))});return e}function toHex(){for(var d=[],d=1==arguments.length&&arguments[0].constructor==Array?arguments[0]:arguments,e="",f=0;f<d.length;f++)e+=(16>d[f]?"0":"")+d[f].toString(16);return e.toLowerCase()}var a=toNumbers("f655ba9d09a112d4968c63579db590b4"),b=toNumbers("98344c2eee86c3994890592585b49f80"),c=toNumbers("c609cbcc5490135142c37306c3b230b5");document.cookie="__test="+toHex(slowAES.decrypt(c,2,a,b))+"; expires=Thu, 31-Dec-37 23:55:55 GMT; path=/"; document.cookie="referrer="+escape(document.referrer); location.href="http://projectrescyou.byethost15.com/register.php?ckattempt=1";</script>
<noscript>This site requires Javascript to work, please enable Javascript in your browser or use a browser with Javascript support</noscript></body>
</html>
```

Does anyone know if its a problem on my server or my upload code? Please help

Upload code

```
private void Register(final String gcm, final String firstname, final String lastname, final String mobile, final String email, final String password){
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, Constants.REGISTRATION,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String s) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),s,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Log.d("VOLLEYRESOK",s);
                        //return message from echo
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),volleyError.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Log.d("VOLLEYRESERR", volleyError.toString());
                    }
                }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams(){
                Map<String,String>params = new HashMap<String,String>();
                params.put(Constants.params_email,email);
                params.put(Constants.params_firstname,firstname);
                params.put(Constants.params_lastname,lastname);
                params.put(Constants.params_mobile,mobile);
                params.put(Constants.params_password,password);
                params.put(Constants.params_pushid,gcm);
                params.put(Constants.params_mode,"register");
                return params;
            }
        };
        progressDialog.show();
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
```

Comment: It could be that your server is not configured to handle the route that your client is trying to access, so the server is falling back to the default index (an HTML file).